# How to create a list of algorithms?

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, algorithms

I have created the following algorithm command in the preamble:

```
\counterwithin{algo}{chapter} 
\newcommand{\algo}[3]{\refstepcounter{algo}
    {
        \centering
        \framebox[\textwidth]{
        \parbox{0.95\textwidth} {\vspace{\topsep}
        {\bf Algorithm \thealgo : #2}\label{#1}\\
        \vspace*{-\topsep} \mbox{ }\\
        {#3} \vspace{\topsep} }}
    }}
```

How can I create a list of Algorithms like `\listoffigures` or `\listoftables`?

Comment: See the documentation of the `tocloft` package (`texdoc tocloft`).

Comment: It depends on which algorithm package you are using.  Some combine formatting and float type, some separate the two, and I imagine some have no float type associated.  For the last case, use newfloat to create a new float type with a corresponding \listof...